# Add styles to console.table() in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I am building a simple Unit-test method in JavaScript. The output is being printed in the console.

I want the rows of the passed tests to be green, and the failed tests to be red (background or text).

I know I can add styles to the console.log(), but I have not found a way to add styles to the console.table().

So, is it even possible? If not, what would be an alternative.

**Code example:**

```
console.table([
    {
        status:   'failed',
        function: 'Validate.int',
        asserted: true,
        result:   false
    },{
        status:   'passed',
        function: 'Validate.float',
        asserted: true,
        result:   true
    }
]);
```

Tnx in advance!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it feets your needs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though @faby created a nice example to use the console.log(), I still didn't found it applicable for my problem. I did also come to the conclusion that adding styles to the console.table() is not possible.

I came up with a solution that nests the results into groups, showing the table nested inside:

```
console.groupCollapsed('Testing unit: %s', unit);
for (var r in results) {
    var res = results[r];
    console.groupCollapsed('%c  %c' + res.status, 'background-color: ' + (res.status === 'failed' ? 'red' : 'green') + '; margin-right: 10px', 'background-color: transparent');
    console.table({
        Result:   {value: res.status},
        Function: {value: res.function},
        Asserted: {value: res.asserted},
        Returned: {value: res.returned}
    });
    console.groupEnd();
}
console.groupEnd();
```

This gives the following output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 4):

Try using `console.log` inside `console.table` and use the styles

working and tested code:

```
console.table(console.log('%c test1 ', 'background: #cdcdcd; color: #000000'),console.log('%c test2 ', 'background: #ff0000; color: #ffffff'));
```

for your case you can do this

```
var x = {
            status: 'failed',
            function: 'Validate.int',
            asserted: true,
            result: false
        };

console.table(
        console.log('%c '+ x.status + x.function  + ' ', 'background: #cdcdcd; color: #000000'), add other elements of the array);
```

replace my `x` with elements of your array

Comment: That doesn't seem to affect the table, but it adds another line with the styled output. I like the idea though

Comment: @ChrisLaarman why don't work? I've tested my code. Show me your code and I'll try to help you

Comment: Check my code. I am passing an array of objects (for that is what the table is for).

Comment: @faby Regarding the new update, you could implement a wrapper that does what the OP wants.

Comment: That still just creates new log lines instead of a table. console.table() doesn't actually do anything in your example. That is because the console.log() directly outputs to the console and returns undefined. My current bet is that it is not possible and I have to use the console.log() instead

Comment: in your question you wrote **If not, what would be an alternative** I have written an example of working code and tested when you can output every line with a different background. I was just trying to help you

Comment: I understand and I appreciate (upvoted). However if you're running unit tests, a list of log lines won't suffice. That's why I wanted to use the table. I came up with a solution that's nesting the results in groups, showing the 'rotated' table inside

Comment: @ChrisLaarman Happy to help you and I'm happy because you've found a solution for your problem :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a hard one to please ;)